# Gnome Panel too Narrow

Tags: gnome-panel

My Gnome Classic Panel in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS was too narrow. Is there a way to make it wider? Usually the panel is as wide as the whole screen.

I was able to fix the problem by resetting the whole panel. I would like to know whether of not this is intended behaviour or a software bug.

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> and right click on the panel there should be an option "Expand" that you need to click.